# is there a diffeomorphism with only finite orbits but of infinite order?

Tags: differential-topology, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

**Note:** after not receiving any answer for some time, I [asked this in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204516/is-there-a-diffeomorphism-with-only-finite-orbits-but-of-infinite-order), and got an answer [there](https://mathoverflow.net/a/204524/46290).

**The Question:**

Is it possible for a diffeomorphism $\phi$ (of a smooth manifold $M$) to have the following properties:

1. **All** its orbits are finite.
2. $\phi$ is **not** of finite order. (and hence has arbitrarily large finite orbits).

There are such examples if we allow infinitely many connected components (Take for instance countable disjoint copies of $\mathbb{S}^1$ and rotation of order $n$ in the $n$-th copy).

So let us assume $M$ is connected. (I prove below that we can reduce the case of finitely many components to one component).

I will add that this question was inspired by a previous question of mine, about [global obstructions for a diffeomorphism to be an isometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203330/is-there-a-global-obstruction-for-a-diffeomorphism-to-be-an-isometry) (You can see the **update** there for the relevant connection).

**Update:**
It turns out the answer is negative. There is no such a diffeomorphism.
(For details [see the answer in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/204524/46290)).

---

**Claim:** existence of a self-diffeomorphism for a manifold with finitely many connected components, implies existence for a connected manifold.

**Proof:**  In this case the components $U_i$ are clopen connected sets, hence $\phi(U_i)$ are also clopen connected sets. Now combine the following two facts:

1. [clopen sets are always a union of connected components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902313/why-are-clopen-sets-a-union-of-connected-components).
2. every connected subset of a topological space $X$ is contained in a connected component $X$.

Now it is evident that each $\phi(U_i)$ is a connected component, i.e $\phi$ permutes the components. Since there are finitely many components, if we choose some component $U_i$, we will get $\phi^n(U_i)=U_i$ for sufficiently large  $n$.

Next, we observe that the if $\phi$ has the two required properties, then $\phi^n$ also has them.

So finally, $\phi^n|_{U_i}$ is a self-diffeomoprhism of a **connected**  manifold with the required properties.

Comment: @mixedmath The way I have dealt with this in the past is to post a community wiki answer linking to the MO post where this is answered, possibly summarizing the details, and accepting this answer. This makes it so people searching and finding this question won't be discouraged by the hold, and will find the answer.

Comment: @MikeMiller I like that more. Let's do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been successfully asked and [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204516/is-there-a-diffeomorphism-with-only-finite-orbits-but-of-infinite-order) on MO. The answer is **no**.